# 1С 7.7 Как сделать динамическое добавление значения по ключу в документ?

Tags: 1с

Есть документ которому присвоены разные реквизиты. Список этих реквизитов и значений для них храниться в таблице значений `ТЗ.Ключ; ТЗ.Значение;`.
Вопрос в том как проходя циклом по всем реквизитам установить им значения?

Нужно сделать нечто вроде:

```
    Док = СоздатьОбъект("Документ.НазваниеДокумента");
    Док.Новый();
    Для ... Цикл

       Док.Установить(Реквизит,значение);  // Здесь и вопрос как реализовать :(

    КонецЦикла;
```

Решение: Док.УстановитьАтрибут(НазваниеРеквизита,Значение);

Comment: @СardinalTroy, имеется в виду, что есть таблица значений, где ключ - наименование реквизита документа, а значение - само значение?

Comment: Да верно, пытался через шаблоны сделать: 
https://helpf.pro/faq7/view/37.html
но оно работает для переменных, а если присваивание реквизиту то не выходит чтото(

Comment: @СardinalTroy, а какая версия 1С?

Comment: @СardinalTroy, ёжики колючие. Старенькая. В ней у меня опыта совсем чуть, чуть (

Comment: Только не понял, что имеется под "реквизит". Реквизит вроде и есть переменная документа.

Comment: @Sagittarius ну вот создаётся документ с реквизитами "номер,дата и т.д.", весь их список у меня храниться, по нему и создаётся документ. Т.е. итоговая цель, имея набор названий реквизитов и их значений, создать документ

Comment: а там нельзя к реквизитам вот так обращаться?

`Документ["ТутИмяРеквизита"] = Значение;`

Comment: @Sagittarius нет увы нельзя, пишет мол не массив

Comment: во как. Гм-м, видно там кардинально отличается от восьмой версии язык (((