# 1С 7.7 Динамическое присваивание Перечисления через Док.УстановитьАтрибут()

Tags: 1с

Продолжение предыдущего [вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1378390/282213) но теперь с реквизитом типа "Перечисление" конкретно.

Я использую следующий код, он работает но надо иначе:

```
Переч = "ПризнакЗаказа";
Знач = "Открыт";
Док.УстановитьЗначение("названиеРеквизита", Перечисление.ПризнакЗаказа.ЗначениеПоИдентификатору(Знач) );
```

Вопрос в том, как менять не только значение (Знач), а и название самого перечисления, имеется ввиду что названия могут быть разные приходить, и получать значения с разных перечислений???

Comment: А можете скинуть базу или хоть что-то, чтобы мне запустить 7.7? Даже любопытно стало, как там вообще работает...

Comment: @Sagittarius увы не имею права вообще.

Comment: Ну хотя бы саму платформу. Чтобы пустую базу развернул.

Answer (score 1):

Лучше всего подошло использование присваивание через шаблоны+вызов функции:
https://helpf.pro/faq7/view/37.html.

Просто шаблоном присвоить не выйдет ибо он возвращает строку, по этому сработал костыль через вызов функции в которой уже присваивается.

```
функция Присвоить(Что, Чему)
   Док.УстановитьЗначение(Чему,Что);
   Возврат "";
КонецФункции

Процедура СформироватьДок()
   Значение = "Перечисление.ПризнакЗаказа.Открыт";
   Реквизит = "ПризнакЗакрытия"; // имя реквизита на форме 
   Шаблон("[Присвоить("+(Значение)+","""+Реквизит+""")]");

КонецПроцедуры
```

Comment: Хоть по ссылке есть решение, лучше в ответе явно добавить код, а ссылку оставить как источник информации

Comment: @gil9red добавил код